# Как обрезать пробелы в текстовом поле при вставке текста с пробелами?

Tags: javascript, html, input

На данный момент есть скрипт, который запрещает вводить пробелы в текстовое поле (`input`). Как не только запрещать их вводить, но и обрезать пробелы при вставке текста, если они там есть?

```html
<input type="text" name="name" onkeypress="return check(event);">

<script type="text/javascript">
  function check(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 32) {
      return false;
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: нужно удалять все пробелы или только лидирующие и завершающие?

Comment: @fellzo нужно удалять все

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно навесить обработчик на событие `onpaste` пример кода:

```js
var myInput = document.getElementById('name'),
  cleanSpaces;

cleanSpaces = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var pastedText = '';
  if (window.clipboardData && window.clipboardData.getData) {
    pastedText = window.clipboardData.getData('Text');
  } else if (e.clipboardData && e.clipboardData.getData) {
    pastedText = e.clipboardData.getData('text/plain');
  }
  this.value = pastedText.replace(/\s/g, '');
};

myInput.onpaste = cleanSpaces;

function check(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == 32) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="name" onkeypress="return check(event);">
```

Ссылка на источник: [Javascript - Removing spaces on paste](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11944089/5275890)

Comment: скопированный текст не вставляется в строку

Comment: @Pavel, опишите подробнее, что у Вас не вставляется? Может у Вас буфер пустой? Скопируйте кусок текста и вставьте.

Comment: я ошибся, всё работает, спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

Описание работы в ответе @fellzo :)

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var txtInput = document.getElementById('txt');
  txtInput.addEventListener('input', function() {
    check(txtInput);
  });
}

function check(input) {
  var newValue = input.value.replace(/\s/g, '');

  if (input.value != newValue) {
    input.value = newValue;
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="txt" type="text" name="name" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Привязать к отправке формы и изменению input'а фукнцию, которая меняет значение формы на значение без пробелов. Для этого можно использовать строковый метод replace(' ', ''), которая заменит каждый пробел на пустую подстроку.

```js
function replace_spaces(event) {
  event.target.value = event.target.value.replace(' ', '');
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="inp" oninput="replace_spaces(event)">
```

Comment: исправляет только два слова, между которыми пробел. если же вставить текст, где множество пробелов - скрипт игнорируется

Comment: @Pavel просто нужно повесить обработку события onpaste